# DependencyProperty CoerceValue & ChangedCallback

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I'm trying to create a custom simply Numeric Up Down using Dependency Properties to practice.

But i'm having some unwanted behavior.

My code:

**XAML:**

```
<Grid Height="22">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBox 
            x:Name="PART_TextboxEditable"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=parent, Mode=TwoWay}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditable, ElementName=parent}"
            PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput"
            FontWeight="Normal">
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RepeatButton 
            Click="IncressValueClick"
            FontSize="8"
            Background="#FFF6F6F6"
            BorderThickness="0 1 1 1">
        <RepeatButton.Content>
                <Path
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    Fill="Black" 
                    Data="M4,0 L0,4 L8,4 z"/>
            </RepeatButton.Content>
        </RepeatButton>
    <RepeatButton 
        Click="DecressValueClick"
        Grid.Row="1"
        FontSize="8"
        BorderThickness="0 0 1 1"
        Background="#FFF6F6F6">
        <RepeatButton.Content>
                <Path 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    Fill="Black" 
                    Data="M0,0 L8,0 L4,4 z"/>
            </RepeatButton.Content>
        </RepeatButton>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Interação lógica para IntegerUpDown.xam
/// </summary>
public partial class IntegerUpDown : UserControl
{
    public int Value
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public int Minimum
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MinimumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinimumProperty, value); }
    }

    public int? Maximum
    {
        get { return (int?)GetValue(MaximumProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaximumProperty, value); }
    }

    public int Increment
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(IncrementProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IncrementProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IncrementProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Increment",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(IntegerUpDown),
            new PropertyMetadata(1));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Maximum",
            typeof(int?),
            typeof(IntegerUpDown),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(MaximumPropertyChangedCallback)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Minimum",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(IntegerUpDown),
            new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(MinimumPropertyChangedCallback)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Value",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(IntegerUpDown),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, 
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(ValuePropertyChangedCalllback),
                new CoerceValueCallback(ValuePropertyCoerceValueCallback)));

    public static readonly RoutedEvent ValueChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "ValueChanged", 
        RoutingStrategy.Bubble, 
        typeof(RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<int>), typeof(IntegerUpDown));

    private static void ValuePropertyChangedCalllback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BindingExpression be = (d as IntegerUpDown).GetBindingExpression(ValueProperty);
        if (be != null)
            be.UpdateSource();

        (d as IntegerUpDown).RaiseEvent(new RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<int>((int)e.OldValue, (int)e.NewValue, ValueChangedEvent));
    }

    private static void MinimumPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs baseValue)
    {
        var value = (int)baseValue.NewValue;
        var obj = d as IntegerUpDown;

        obj.SetCurrentValue(ValueProperty, (int)Math.Max(obj.Value, value));
    }

    private static void MaximumPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs baseValue)
    {
        var value = (int?)baseValue.NewValue;
        var obj = d as IntegerUpDown;

        obj.SetCurrentValue(ValueProperty, Math.Min(obj.Value, value ?? obj.Value));
    }

    private static object ValuePropertyCoerceValueCallback(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        var value = (int)baseValue;
        var obj = d as IntegerUpDown;

        obj.CoerceValue(MaximumProperty);
        obj.CoerceValue(MinimumProperty);

        int newValue = Math.Max(obj.Minimum, Math.Min(value, obj.Maximum ?? value));

        return newValue;
    }

    public IntegerUpDown()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void IncressValueClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IncressValue();
    }

    private void DecressValueClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DecressValue();
    }

    private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        var fullText = textBox.Text.Insert(textBox.SelectionStart, e.Text);

        e.Handled = !int.TryParse(fullText, out _);
    }

    private void NumericUpDownPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        IntegerUpDown control = (IntegerUpDown)sender;

        e.Handled = control.Focus() || e.Handled;
    }

    private void Parent_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta > 0)
            IncressValue();
        else
            DecressValue();
    }

    private void IncressValue()
    {
        Value += Increment;
    }

    private void DecressValue()
    {
        Value -= Increment;
    }
    private void Parent_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Up:
                IncressValue();
                break;

            case Key.Down:
                DecressValue();
                break;

            default:
                return;
        }
    }
```

It's a very simply code but it's not working as expected. I know I'm doing something wrong but I can't recognize the problem here.

Problem:

I'm using that XAML to test:

```
<local:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding Value}" 
                     Maximum="15"
                     Minimum="10"
                     Increment="2"></local:IntegerUpDown>

<TextBlock 
    Foreground="White"
    Text="{Binding Value}" Grid.Row="1"></TextBlock>
```

As you can see below, I set manually writing '15151515' value to `TextBox` and my `CoerceValue` it's called, my `newValue` returned to `CoerceValue` is '15' because `Maximum` value it's set to 15. My `textbox` show the correct value (15) but my value from `ViewModel` have the incorrect value.

[[image: 1]

If I press UP and my value it's 15:

[[image: 2]]

I have my `Maximum` always something like `Maximum` + `Increment` and `Minimum` - `Increment`. I mean, when the value arrive to `Minimum`, I can click one more time and have `Minimum` - `Increment` (on example is 8) on `ViewModel` but on `TextBox` it's showing the `MinimumValue` (on example is 10).

Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CoerceValueCallback` is run *after* the source property has been set. You can work around this by setting the `DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger` property of the dependency property to `UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit` and explicitly set the source property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Value",
                typeof(int),
                typeof(IntegerUpDown),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(ValuePropertyChangedCalllback),
                    new CoerceValueCallback(ValuePropertyCoerceValueCallback))
                { DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit });
...
private static void ValuePropertyChangedCalllback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    IntegerUpDown ctrl = (IntegerUpDown)d;
    int newValue = (int)e.NewValue;
    BindingExpression be = ctrl.GetBindingExpression(ValueProperty);
    if (be != null && be.ResolvedSource != null && be.ParentBinding != null && be.ParentBinding.Path != null
        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(be.ParentBinding.Path.Path))
    {
        var pi = be.ResolvedSource.GetType().GetProperty(be.ParentBinding.Path.Path);
        if (pi != null)
            pi.SetValue(be.ResolvedSource, newValue);
    }

    ctrl.RaiseEvent(new RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<int>((int)e.OldValue, newValue, ValueChangedEvent));
}
```

Comment: It's that the only way to workaround this? How Slider and other controls of WPF make the same job?

Comment: @KevinKouketsu: They don't. There is nothing stopping you from setting the `Value` of a `Slider` to a value that is larger than its `Maximum` and this does update the source property.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is any other option do to the same? To me this approach its like a MacGyver thing. I'm asking this just because I want to learn and not because I didn't like your code

Comment: @KevinKouketsu: I've already showed you a "workaround", haven't I? What's your current issue/question?

Comment: I just want to know other options if possible but yes, you helped me with a "workaround", thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you were asking about slider maybe an explanation of how that works could inspire an alternative.

The way a slider works is that there's a method which changes the Value. This is called whenever a change is necessary and it checks against min max.
Hence this not part of the dp system at all and  the value is decoupled by an intermediary which handles the checking.

Just setting the value of the dependency property ignores this internal method so no min/max is applied.

Because you have a textbox you can't "just" re-template a slider and use it's inbuilt behaviour.

You could instead use a similar pattern though.

Add an internal dp to hold the input value.

Let's call that invalue.

Bind that to the textbox.

When invalue is changed, check vs min/max and set your external value or reset the invalue.

When the repeatbuttons are pressed, check whether against the min/max values before setting both invalue and value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you provide some snippet to test?